# ProxyPass with 2 cases

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

Having these two rules works good:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app
```

When client visits, domain.com, Apache calls app server and it works as expected.

Problem is that there is one directory, generated by the app server that I don't want to be prepended with */app*.

For example:

```
domain.com/app/styles/file.css (actual case)
domain.com/styles/files.css  (this is how I want this)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I added answer, but it occurred to me ... is stuff in the app server linking to /app/styles/file.css or just /styles/file.css; the former may require rewriting the HTML on the file.

Comment: correct, first case, stuff in the app server. Can't rewrite it's coded on the app server, not in my code.

Comment: Oops... I meant on the fly, as in using mod_rewrite_html or whatever

Comment: To possibly help clarify, could you provide an example of WHY you don't want it to prepended by /app

Comment: @Foon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203177/apache-in-front-of-jsf

Answer (score -1):

I'm still not 100% sure which way your issue is.
If you want it so that when the browser sees something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

It requests the **main.css** file that tomcat hosts at `/app/styles/main.css`

Try:

```
ProxyPass /styles http://localhost:8080/app/styles
ProxyPassReverse /styles http://localhost:8080/app/styles

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app
```

Conversely, if you want it so that when the browser sees something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/apps/styles/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

It gets the **main.css** file that tomcat hosts at `/styles/main.css`

Try:

```
ProxyPass /apps/styles http://localhost:8080/styles
ProxyPassReverse /apps/styles http://localhost:8080/styles

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app
```

In either case, Apache will match in the order stuff appears in the config file.

Comment: Also note that if stuff in /styles/ is all static files, you could move it into your httpd wwwroot (e.g. /var/www/html) and do something like: ProxyPass /styles ! to cause it to serve it from Apache httpd instead of tomcat or whatever your app server is.

Comment: nope cannot do that either, it's dynamic content :(

Comment: You might need to combine rewrite with ProxyPass, or use another context under /app/ to use with ProxyPass.